# Mojo: "Error: An error occurred in Python."

Tags: python, modular, mojolang

I am trying out Mojo by Modular and more specifically having a look at the `Mandelbrot.ipynb` available [here](https://github.com/modularml/mojo/blob/main/examples/notebooks/Mandelbrot.ipynb). When running the line `np = Python.import_module("numpy")` I get the rather odd error `Error: An error occurred in Python.`. I have had a look around and only found [this](https://github.com/modularml/mojo/issues/590) open issue. Has anyone experienced the same issue previously and reached a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read tag descriptions (the tooltip from hovering over the tag is usually enough) before using them. The `mojo` tag doesn't have anything to do with Python, I changed it to `mojolang` for you. `modular` could mean lots of different things, and in fact the tag wiki appears to be empty.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for correcting it, I could not find the correct mojo tag when writing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to make sure you have numpy installed, or check the compatibility of mojo with your python version and Review the code in the Mandelbrot.ipynb notebook aware. Make sure there are no syntax errors or logical problems in your code that could cause the error.

Comment: My packages were not installed in my python environment. Should have thought of that sooner 

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everyone, I'm happy to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can we use virtual environments with Mojo, or is it better to install the packages in global python packages?

Edit: I just found that Mojo provides a dockerfile, found here, https://github.com/modularml/mojo/blob/main/examples/docker/Dockerfile.mojosdk.